# CTE - get the parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there were plenty of question of CTE but I still don't know how to do that.
I have table Messages with columns: id and previousMessageId. How can I get the parent for id = 957 - it should be: 950.

```
table Messages
--------------
id  | previousMessageId
957 | 956
956 | 950
950 | NULL
```

This is my query:

```
WITH previous AS 
( 
    SELECT id  
    FROM Messages 
    WHERE id = 957 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT cur.id 
    FROM Messages cur
    INNER JOIN previous ON cur.previousMessageID = previous.id
) 
SELECT * FROM previous
```

It gives me:

```
957
958
```

But the result should be: 950

Comment: Fascinating.  You don't even have 955 in the data, and the query is supposed to return that?

Comment: My mistake, of course 950, very sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like following.

```
declare @table table(id int,   previousMessageId int)
insert into @table select 957 , 956
insert into @table select 956 , 950
insert into @table select 950 , NULL
insert into @table select 999 , 998
insert into @table select 998 , 997
insert into @table select 997 , NULL

;WITH previous 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                previousmessageid 
         FROM   @table 
         WHERE  id = 957
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT cur.id, 
                cur.previousmessageid 
         FROM   @table cur 
                INNER JOIN previous 
                        ON cur.id = previous.previousmessageid) 
SELECT ID 
FROM   previous 
WHERE  previousmessageid IS NULL
```

In above example, for Id 957 you will get 950  and for Id 999 you will get 997

Comment: Thx You very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a second column to denote the parent id. The parent layer will have a null column the child layer will then reference the parent layer.

```
WITH previous AS 
( 
SELECT id, null as parentid  
FROM Messages 
WHERE id = 957 

UNION ALL 

SELECT cur.id, cur.previousMessageID 
FROM Messages cur
INNER JOIN previous ON cur.previousMessageID = previous.id
) 
SELECT ParentID FROM previous where ParentID is not null
```

Comment: it gives: id parentid
957 NULL
958 957

Comment: I've edited the query to only show the parentid where it is not null.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @table table(id int,   previousMessageId int)
insert into @table select 957 , 956
insert into @table select 956 , 950
insert into @table select 950 , NULL
insert into @table select 999 , 998
insert into @table select 998 , 997
insert into @table select 997 , NULL;

with cte as (
    -- base case - get all records with no parent
    select *, 
        cast(concat('/', id, '/') as varchar(max)) as [path],
        id as [root]
    from @table
    where previousMessageId is null

    union all

    -- recursive step
    select child.*, 
        concat(parent.path, child.id, '/'),
        parent.root
    from @table as child
    join cte as parent
        on parent.id = child.previousMessageId
)
select *
from cte
where id = 957;
```

The `root` column in the final output is the first in the line of ancestors that ends with that particular ID. As to how I accomplished it, the trick is essentially always carrying the `parent.root` forward through the recursion step.